# django and react, simplest way to integrate

Tags: reactjs, django, hybrid

I have a react app created using "create-react-app" that I would like to connect to a backend, now due to the fact I already use django and like how it simplifies many of the redundant tasks, I chose it as my backend.

In many articles the recommended way of using it is using django_rest_framework and making api calls from the react app, I neglected a very important point here as I thought I could have django serve the simple static pages and use react only for the js heavy tasks (which in my case is only one page and the main point of the website).

my questions are, can I keep user logged in if he navigates from the simple html pages to the app (in case they live on separate servers) ?

If not possible how can I integrate a create-react-app project with django ?